# Identifying this winged ant with big hind legs

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this walking across my floor not too long ago. I am not sure if it is actually an ant, I just chose the best words I could find for the title. It has wings, but does not seem to ever fly. It has antennae and the hind legs looks much larger than I've ever seen on an ant. Moreover, they seem to have a red tint. Any ideas?

Area: U.S. East Coast

[image: Side view. See red, large hind leg.]
[image: Another side view.]
[image: Underside view]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! That looks more like a wasp of some sort than an ant. Please [edit] your post to include an estimate of the size of this insect since that can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— If possible clearer, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Finally, please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Yes, that is a wasp. The legs are distinctive of that family, butI've forgotten the name.

Comment: I think it might be some kind of Conura. There are photos at https://bugguide.net/node/view/18810/bgpage which resemble yours. And according to that page it's in roughly the right area of America. But there are a lot of wasp species in the Conura genus and I don't know if other wasps in the chalcid family have those large hind legs. So... inconclusive.

Comment: The expanded hind femora are a feature of the Chalcididae as a whole, but are not unique to that family within Chalcidoidea (the related family Leucospidae also have them, but are much larger and might be mistaken for potter wasps at first glance [at least in North America]).